# Matching on multiple variables in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to count / list persons with a specific skill for each employer/Organisation. The skill is determined for a person based on whether one has completed one of two specific course events). A person can either [:WORK_AT]-->Dep-[:PART_OF]->Org or [:WORK_AT]->Org. Using the enclosed (inelegant) code I am able to list persons for a single Org, but struggle to find ways to do this for all Org(anisations) (employers).

```
MATCH (p:Person)-->(l:Event), (o:Org)<--()<-[:WORKS_AT]-(p:Person) 
WHERE (l.name="course a1" OR l.name="course a2") 
AND o.name="University A" 
RETURN o.name, count(DISTINCT(p))
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is a perfect case where you might have an optional connection/relationship that may or may not be there.

Traditionally you might look to UNION to do this, but we actually have a knowledge base article on [alternatives to UNION queries](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/alternatives-to-union-queries/) that provide another option, where we use a variable-length relationship with a lower-bound of 0, meaning we can match paths where that relationship doesn't even exist in the pattern.

In your case, usage would look like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-->(l:Event), (o:Org)<-[:PART_OF*0..1]-()<-[:WORKS_AT]-(p:Person) 
WHERE (l.name="course a1" OR l.name="course a2") 
AND o.name="University A" 
RETURN o.name, count(DISTINCT(p))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... that did indeed solve my problem (without the ´AND o.name "University A"´)

Comment: I have tried to use a similar MATCH as that of the above to show the graph; however, I only get those Person who has a direct relationship to Org (not with the alternative path of Person-[:WORKS_AT]->Dep-[:PART_OF]->Org. The Persons with a P-Dep-Org path are shown without any Org or Dep relation.

// match
MATCH (p:Person)-[:MEMBER_OF]-(l:Project)-[:HOSTED_BY]-(i:Infrastructure), (o:Org)<-[:PART_OF*0..1]-()<-[:WORKS_AT]-(p:Person) WHERE i.name="LHC" return DISTINCT(p), l, o, i

Comment: @AndreasJaunsen You'll want to check if the relationships in question actually exist, typos for the relationship type, or a mistake in the direction, would cause it not to match. For additional help for your case, try asking on the [Neo4j community forums](https://community.neo4j.com/)